# <select> lose their focus after add Bootstrap tooltip in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I find out that if I change any attribute on `<select>` element in IE 11 then this element losing their focus what is effecting that elements going to close select list, so if I bind any action changing `.attr()` to `click` or `focus` events I cannot use this select any more (after each click it will close itself automatically). When I changed it to `.prop()` everything work fine...

The problem starts when I want to show Bootstrap tooltip on click (first time) -> it's closing select list. Solution which I know is add tooltip to parent element e.g `.form-group` but I cannot change my structure.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odx7q0tn/4/)

Is any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: This fiddle seems to work the exact same for me in chrome vs ie 11 on win7

Comment: X-Ref: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14764